# Using ShaderGraph for UI elements with transparency

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I am trying to design some UI elements using shader graph. In this case specifically a life bar that is transparent where empty.

For a normal life bar with a filled and empty color I got it working without much issue. I created my shader using an unlit model, and set it to a material. I set the material on a raw image, and then added it to a canvas.

Now I want to create a life bar with transparency. It I make the shader transparent, I just get a black box. If I make it opaque I can see the shader, but the transparent (alpha blended) sections of the image are just black. I cannot find any settings to fix this. The shader looks fine outside of UI with the transparency working.

Is there a way to make raw images on a shader graph support transparency even if it is just yes/no per pixel transparency?
Is a raw image the correct way to use a shader on UI?

Answer (score 0):

## You're looking for Alpha Cutoff

*Or alpha test.*

There are some builtin shaders that do this, but the general idea is to check the alpha value of the texture (which goes from 0% to 100% from one side to the other) and compare that value with a float property (driven by your player's HP). If it's less, output 0. If it's more, output 1.

It tends to leave a jagged edge, though, which is one of the reasons I created [these shaders](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/alpha-cutout-shaders-16429) a number of years ago. It treats that boundary a little more fuzzily so that any imperfections in the texture are blurred out, as well as allowing for edges that aren't completely hard. I tend to get the best results with a blend value of about `0.02`; small enough that some blurring occurs, but not so strongly that the data precision (i.e. the readability of the graphic) is lost. $2 asset is $2 because that's the lowest non-free price and anyone with understanding of HSLS can create the included shaders themselves in about an hour.

I'm not sure how ShaderGraph would handle this, if there's already a builtin function for it (I'd be surprised if there wasn't), but creating it manually with a few nodes should be easy enough now that you know what the process is.